# How to mandate all pods in namespace to be marked with label key=value upon creation

Tags: kubernetes, policies

Would it be possible to mandate developers (by creating policies on in some other way) to mark all of their pods/resources with pre-defined label , e.g. environment=dev or department=dev ?

It can be in the form of enforcement ( e.g. if pod is created without propel label - deny the creation request) or just silently apply necessary label and re-write the existing one if needed.

Answer (score 2):

I gave [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58841928/9889148) to a similar question regarding "...policy check before container execution".

In essence, [Open Policy Agent](https://www.openpolicyagent.org/) - a Cloud Native Computing Foundation (incubating) project - supports custom policy enforcement for Kubernetes. Check out this [example](https://github.com/open-policy-agent/gatekeeper#constraint-templates) regarding enforcing labels to be present.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Admission controller is the only way to accomplish it - https://kubernetes.io/blog/2019/03/21/a-guide-to-kubernetes-admission-controllers/