# Configure a pod in inherit namespace label

Tags: kubernetes, namespaces

I have a cluster and my goal is to configure pods in such a way that they will inherit a label from the namespace that they are located in. Is it possible to achieve this functionality using admission controllers? Do you know if this can be easily achieved on the latest version of Kubernetes?

Answer (score 0):

We can use both [Admission Controllers](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2019/03/21/a-guide-to-kubernetes-admission-controllers/) and [Open Policy Agent](https://www.openpolicyagent.org/) for enforcing policy. These policies can be enforcing the same label to pods from namespace etc.,

There is a similar issue discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59199675/). Please check for your reference.